# Working in the childview of a ListView, how can I reference all the items in order to perform a method?

Tags: listview, parent-child, onitemclicklistener

I set a project where by clicking on an expandableListView, a further child listview shows up. Yet, I would like to render all the child item clickable in order to inflate a fragment. I assume an onItemClickLIstener + inflate method and reference of the xml layout would work out, but how do I do that? Moreover, in which class would I need to put it?
Here's my class with all the items of the childview (of course it's a separate class from the Main_Activity one).

```
public class DataProvider {

public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getInfo()
{
    HashMap<String, List<String>> MoviesDetails = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> Action_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
    Action_Movies.add("AM1");
    Action_Movies.add("AM2");
    Action_Movies.add("AM3");
    Action_Movies.add("AM4");

    List<String> Romantic_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
    Romantic_Movies.add("RM1");
    Romantic_Movies.add("RM2");
    Romantic_Movies.add("RM3");
    Romantic_Movies.add("RM4");

    List<String> Horror_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
    Horror_Movies.add("HM1");
    Horror_Movies.add("HM2");
    Horror_Movies.add("HM3");
    Horror_Movies.add("HM4");

    List<String> Comedy_Movies = new ArrayList<String>();
    Comedy_Movies.add("CM1");
    Comedy_Movies.add("CM2");
    Comedy_Movies.add("CM3");
    Comedy_Movies.add("CM4");

    MoviesDetails.put("Action Movies", Action_Movies);
    MoviesDetails.put("Romantic Movies", Romantic_Movies);
    MoviesDetails.put("Horror Movies", Horror_Movies);
    MoviesDetails.put("Comedy Movies", Comedy_Movies);

    return MoviesDetails;
}
```

Comment: got it with the onChildClickListener; now, how do I define each element?

The general statement is     (ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)

Should I use the "i" for the group and "i1" for the child?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch(groupPosition) {
                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent X = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
                            startActivity(X);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent X2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
                            startActivity(X2);
                            break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 2:
                            Intent Y = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LastActivity.class);
                            startActivity(Y;
                            break;
```

yet, how do I inflate a fragment, rather than opening a new activity?